# Bruges - Where can I find this gate/entrance?

Tags: identify-this, belgium, bruges

[image: http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/brugges1.jpg]

I'm looking for the gate at the top of the picture ("Jupiler Bleeker"). I only know it's in Bruges... Can someone give me the exact location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is: [Blekerstraat, Brugge](https://www.google.fr/maps/@51.2129858,3.2300185,3a,75y,318.94h,81.63t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sPO8l6Ahq_UY3hItp1aiUFg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=fr) (link to google map):

[image: Jupiler Bleeker, Brugge]

This is next to Café Vlissinghe, Brugge’s oldest operating café.